# Error en Laravel: Whoops, looks like something went wrong

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Estoy trabajando un proyecto de aprendizaje y decidí llevármelo de una pc a otra (sistema+base de datos), levanto mi servicio con php artisan serve lo carga pero no puedo ver mi información, me sale el siguiente error: Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

Intenté activar el debug en el archivo config/app pero no me muestra más que esa palabra.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Laravel?

Comment: 5.6.  Saludos Shaz!

Comment: Porque no pruebas con el comando php artisan key:generate, aunque la verdad me gustaría que colgaras algunas capturas de pantalla

Comment: y si mejor lo pasas en wamp/xampp (no mencionaste si cargaste la db)? O prueba con php artisan config:cache / php artisan cache.clear (laravel a veces da problemas con eso)

Comment: @PAGANA no es una buena idea utilizar wamp o xampp cuando Laravel tiene algo muchísimo más potente llamado Homestead.

Comment: Ya probé con el comando, el problema es que veo que algunos nombres de mis archivos cambiaron, por ejemplo el .env se cambó a _env esto ocurrió luego de que lo subí a google drive.